# Sort array of string by day of week

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray containing abbreviated days of the week, `sun`, `mon`, `tue`, `wed`, `thu`, `fri`, `sat`. I am trying to sort it so that they will always be in this order, no matter which days are there, and/or their current order. How do I sort the string so that they are always in the right order?

I tried using

```
    NSArray* sorted = [parent.medication.days sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* obj1, NSString* obj2) {

        // sort by position of id string in order array..
        NSUInteger obj1Pos = [idsInOrder indexOfObject:obj1[@"sun"] ];
        NSUInteger obj2Pos = [idsInOrder indexOfObject:obj2[@"mon"] ];

        return [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:obj1Pos] compare:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:obj2Pos]];
    }];
```

But all that did was throw errors on me, and it didn't even include all 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `[@"sun"]` and `[@"mon"]` from the lines where you call `indexOfObject:`.